# In Python, what does it mean for a function to be "total"?

Tags: python

I'm taking an MIT opencourse thingy and there's this code in their first quiz.

```
def f(s):
    d = {}
    for c in s:
        if c in d.keys():
            d[c] += 1
        else: d[c] = 1
    print d
    x = None
    for k in d.keys():
        if x == None:
            x = d[k]
            y = k
        elif d[k] > x:
            x = d[k]
            y = k
    return y
```

The question in question is:

> Is f total, i.e., defined for all values of s of type str?

I'm thinking that f is total because anything in a string, including numbers and special characters, can be put through the code. Am I even close?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Because it's initialized to None?

Comment: @Kevin, yes, mixed up k and x

Comment: Looks like a [math thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), not a Python thing.

Comment: Really, MIT uses `if c in d.keys()`? Who do I bop over the head to have that corrected to `if c in d`? Same for iteration, `for k in d` is plenty, why the extra calls to `keys()` here?

Comment: could be simply written as  `max(s, key=s.count)`

Comment: @ MartijnPieters I think the `keys()` is there for teaching purposes, probably to emphasize something about dictionaries. I agree with you, though, and I think I would probably write `if c in d` without the `keys()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only case where this couldn't work is the empty string, if they consider that a valid string (I would, as an edge case). For `s = ''`, `y` will never be defined, and you will get

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```

For all non-empty strings, yes the function is "total". According to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalFunction.html) a "total function" is defined as

> A function defined for all possible input values.